# Oozie Setup does not work

Tags: apache, oozie, bigtop

Yet another problem with Apache Bigtop. This time it is oozie.

Whenever I want to do something with Oozie, I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Oozie URL is not available neither in command option or in the environment
```

I did some google-fuu and came across the [tutorial](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/BIGTOP/Running+various+Bigtop+components) officially provided by them.

But hurray, next problem:

Whenever I enter

```
bin/oozie-setup.sh -hadoop 2.6.0 $HADOOP_HOME -extjs ext-2.2.zip
```

I get the following reply:

```
  setting OOZIE_DATA=/var/lib/oozie
  setting OOZIE_CATALINA_HOME=/usr/lib/bigtop-tomcat
  setting CATALINA_TMPDIR=/var/lib/oozie
  setting CATALINA_PID=/var/run/oozie/oozie.pid
  setting CATALINA_BASE=/var/lib/oozie/tomcat-deployment
  setting CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Xmx1024m"
  setting OOZIE_CONFIG=/etc/oozie/conf
  setting OOZIE_LOG=/var/log/oozie
  setting OOZIE_DATA=/var/lib/oozie
  setting OOZIE_CATALINA_HOME=/usr/lib/bigtop-tomcat
  setting CATALINA_TMPDIR=/var/lib/oozie
  setting CATALINA_PID=/var/run/oozie/oozie.pid
  setting CATALINA_BASE=/var/lib/oozie/tomcat-deployment
  setting CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Xmx1024m"
  setting OOZIE_CONFIG=/etc/oozie/conf
  setting OOZIE_LOG=/var/log/oozie

 Usage  : oozie-setup.sh <Command and OPTIONS>
          prepare-war [-d directory] [-secure] (-d identifies an alternative directory for processing jars
                                                -secure will configure the war file to use HTTPS (SSL))
          sharelib create -fs FS_URI [-locallib SHARED_LIBRARY] (create sharelib for oozie,
                                                                FS_URI is the fs.default.name
                                                                for hdfs uri; SHARED_LIBRARY, path to the
                                                                Oozie sharelib to install, it can be a tarball
                                                                or an expanded version of it. If ommited,
                                                                the Oozie sharelib tarball from the Oozie
                                                                installation directory will be used)
                                                                (action failes if sharelib is already installed
                                                                in HDFS)
          sharelib upgrade -fs FS_URI [-locallib SHARED_LIBRARY] (upgrade existing sharelib, fails if there
                                                                  is no existing sharelib installed in HDFS)
          db create|upgrade|postupgrade -run [-sqlfile <FILE>] (create, upgrade or postupgrade oozie db with an
                                                                optional sql File)
          (without options prints this usage information)

 EXTJS can be downloaded from http://www.extjs.com/learn/Ext_Version_Archives
```

I have tried quiet a lot of things. I downloaded a version of ext-2.2.zip from an archive. I downloaded the version 2.3.0. But no matter what I do, the reply stays the same. Please help me get Oozie to run. I desperately need it right now!

Answer (score 0):

Few thing you have to check 1st, as per the link you have shared that is to enable the Oozie UI which required ext-2.2 jar.
So if you already have Oozie setup done then you have to make the oozie.war file, including DB Driver and ext-2.2.zip file

to do so steps you need to perform is

1. download ext-2.2.zip file from source and place the same in OOZIE_HOME/libext folder.
2. download mysql/oracle/postgress driver and place the same in OOZIE_HOME/libext folder.
3. start the oozie-setup.sh scriptr by executing

   $ ./oozie-setup.sh
   these will update the oozie.war file with supported ext-2.2.zip file and other jars which you have place in OOZIE_HOME/libext location.
4. once the above is done, you can go to next step by creating Sharedlib manually by simply coping the uncompress sharedlib.tar.gz file available in OOZIE_HOME location to hdfs://localhost:54310/user/hduser/share/lib
5. Create Oozie DB by executing

   OOZIE_HOME/bin/./ooziedb.sh create -sqlfile oozie.sql -run

NOTE: here oozie.sql is a blank file which you need to mention it could be any name but extension should be .sql, also the DB details need to update in oozie-site.xml under OOZIE_HOME/conf/oozie-site.xml file; if you have not set any DB configuration details the Oozie will Use defualt DB which is DERBY,

6. Finally if all above points have been setup you can start oozie by

   $OOZIE_HOME/./bin/oozied.sh start

and hit the oozie url and check the status.
[Referecnce URL](http://www.rohitmenon.com/index.php/apache-oozie-installation/): Rohit Menon has mention some of the steps which can be done simply.

Answer (score 0):

My Oozie binary (version 5.0.0) is in /home/hduser/oozie/oozie-5.0.0.
About the war file, the tutorial I've followed (https://acadgild.com/blog/beginners-guide-for-oozie-installation) gives this indication :
"Now after setting up the things, move into the bin folder of newly obtained oozie-4.1.0 in the path $HOME/oozie/oozie-4.1.0/" **(for me is $HOME/oozie/oozie-5.0.0)**.

"Now prepare a war file by using the below command : **sudo ./oozie-setup.sh prepare-war** "
but, for my installation this command doesn't worked, because oozie-setup.sh give me the help indication about the usage : 
[image: command reply (part)]

My solution was simply to go one level up from the /bin directory and give this command : hduser@:~/oozie/oozie-5.0.0$ **bin/oozie-setup.sh** (without the string "prepare-war"). This worked for me.